# How do I define partially ordered sets in Lean?

Tags: set, dependent-type, theorem-proving, lean

I wish to prove [this theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/520805/46430) in the Lean theorem prover. First, I need to define things like partially ordered sets so that I can define infimum/supremum. How is this done in Lean? [The tutorial](http://leanprover.github.io/tutorial/tutorial.pdf) mentions setoids, which are types with an
associated equivalence relation. But it is not clear to me how this could help.

Comment: Incidentally, how do you plan to define real numbers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not a Lean user, but here's how I'd define it in Agda. It may not translate directly - there's a lot of variety in type theories - but it should at least be a pointer!

We'll be working with binary logical relations, which are inhabitants of this type synonym:

```
Rel : Set -> Set1
Rel A = A -> A -> Set
```

And we'll need propositional equality:

```
data _==_ {A : Set} (x : A) : A -> Set where
  refl : x == x
```

One can say what it means for a logical relation to be [reflexive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflexive_relation), [antisymmetric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antisymmetric_relation), and [transitive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_relation).

```
Refl : {A : Set} -> Rel A -> Set
Refl {A} _~_ = {x : A} -> x ~ x

Antisym : {A : Set} -> Rel A -> Set
Antisym {A} _~_ = {x y : A} -> x ~ y -> y ~ x -> x == y

Trans : {A : Set} -> Rel A -> Set
Trans {A} _~_ = {x y z : A} -> x ~ y -> y ~ z -> x ~ z
```

To be a partial order, it must be all three.

```
record IsPartialOrder {A : Set} (_<=_ : Rel A) : Set where
  field
    reflexive : Refl _<=_
    antisymmetric : Antisym _<=_
    transitive : Trans _<=_
```

A [poset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set) is just a set equipped with a partial ordering relation.

```
record Poset : Set1 where
  field
    carrier : Set
    _<=_ : Rel carrier
    isPartialOrder : IsPartialOrder _<=_
```

---

For the record (ha ha), here is how the [setoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setoid) example from the tutorial translates into Agda:

```
Sym : {A : Set} -> Rel A -> Set
Sym {A} _~_ = {x y : A} -> x ~ y -> y ~ x

record IsEquivalence {A : Set} (_~_ : Rel A) : Set where
  field
    reflexive : Refl _~_
    symmetric : Sym _~_
    transitive : Trans _~_

record Setoid : Set1 where
  field
    carrier : Set
    _~_ : Rel carrier
    isEquivalence : IsEquivalence _~_
```

---

**Update**: I installed Lean, committed a load of syntax errors, and eventually arrived at this (probably not idiomatic, but straightforward) translation. Functions become `definition`s and `record`s become `structure`s.

```
definition Rel (A : Type) : Type := A -> A -> Prop

definition IsPartialOrder {A : Type}(P : Rel A) :=
  reflexive P ∧ anti_symmetric P ∧ transitive P

structure Poset :=
  (A : Type)
  (P : Rel A)
  (ispo : IsPartialOrder P)
```

I'm using the [built-in versions](https://github.com/leanprover/lean/blob/master/library/init/relation.lean) of the definitions for reflexivity (etc) that I defined myself in Agda above. I also notice that Lean seems happy to let me omit the universe level of `Type` in the return type of `Rel` above, which is a nice touch.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! How do I assert that one of these Posets has a subset? `definition UpperBound {A:Type}{P : Rel A} :=
  take K : Poset A P,
  take S : Poset A P,
  assume S ⊂ K,` is not working. I assume that I need to define the subset operator, I guess it should be an infix operator that takes one set, and one Poset, and asserts that all elements of the set is in the Poset. But how do I assert that something is in the Poset? `take x : A,
  assume x ∈ K,` is not working either...

Comment: Perhaps these warrant separate questions. One good way of defining a subset is with a logical predicate of type `Pred A = A -> Set`. To define membership, any `x : A` is a proof that `A` is not empty.

Answer (score 1):

Lean's standard library already contains definitions of [various orders](https://github.com/leanprover/lean/blob/master/library/data/real/order.lean). However, while [there are](https://github.com/leanprover/lean/blob/87252bbffeb8c0ba4f8554608cc516d407cb915b/library/theories/analysis/real_limit.lean) definitions of `inf` and `sup` for the reals, I don't think there are ones for ℚ, yet (or applicable general definitions, since neither of these types is a `complete_lattice`).